# Number comparison without using if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison

I have numerous comparisons to make. I have used multiple if statements for such, but there are too many and I'm not sure if it's the best coding practice. What can I use to replace them?

For example, I have this:

```
if ((ANum==2) and (Action==1)):
    print ("*some text*")
if ((ANum==2) and (Action==1) and (2.5<=Freq<=4)):
    print("*some text*")
if ((ANum==2) and (1<=FreqMagnitude<=6.5)):
    print("*some text*")
if ((ANum==1) and (Action==0) and (4.5>Freq)):
    print("*some text*")
```

I have like 20 of these statements with different single, double, or triple conditionals. Is there a better coding practice?

Comment: Some of these conditionals could be condensed/nested, such as each of the `ANum == 2` conditions. This doesn't completely answer the question, however.

Comment: You could use `np.select()`, it lets you specify a list of conditions and a list of results if said conditions are met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice, without removing the if's, its to **organice a little**:

From this:

```
if ((ANum==2) and (Action==1) and (2.5<=Freq<=4)):
    print("*some text*")
if ((ANum==2) and (1<=FreqMagnitude<=6.5)):
    print("*some text*")
if ((ANum==1) and (Action==0) and (4.5>Freq)):
    print("*some text*")
```

To this:

```
if(Action==1):
    if(ANum==2):
        if(1<=FreqMagnitude<=6.5):
            print("*some text*")
        if(2.5<=Freq<=4):
            print("*some text*")
if(Action==0):
    if(ANum==1):
        if(4.5>Freq):
            print("*some text*")
```

So if you have another criteria for action ==1 and ANum == 2 you have to only add a new if after the "ANum==2" validation.

**The tip here is**: Identify the "common" criteria and place them at the top, like "coming from general to specific criteria".

If you don't like this, you can try "switch case", but I don't know if the switch supports multiple criteria.

Comment: Thank you!! This is helpful!

Comment: You are welcome, I have to deal with this kind of stuff daily at the work, so you get to identify some tips that make complex ideas a little easier.